# Disabling the viewstate on Gridview leads to different problems

Tags: gridview, viewstate, asp.net-4.0

I am trying to optimize the viewstate of my ASP.NET 4.0 application. 
As the gridview is adding huge amount to teh viewstae I disabled the viewstateMode.
 These are the following problems I have when I disable viewstate.

```
1)  On a postback the Gridview is blank.

2)  In order to overcome the above problem I tried to bind the data in OnPreRender() then I ran into another problem : The Delete (Rowdelte) and Rowcommand doesn't fire.
```

What would be the best place to bind the data to datagrind on a postback so that it won't affect the rest of the events.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you the gridview's datakeynames property since viewstate is disabled.
The Gridview can be databound on postback by removing any if !ispostback.

When you databind in the prerender (the last point you can bind), you are skipping the databound controls' events, which occured before the prerender.

Also, this link,
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.100).aspx, explains the life cycle.
You can review viewstate here, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386448.aspx